# How can i create a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to know how can i create a custom `UITableViewCell` with three parts in the `UITableViewCell` like that:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a blank XIB with a UITableViewCell and design the cell dropping elements on it. Set arbitrary tags (1,2,3...) on each element so you can retrieve them later.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *identifier = @"xxx";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfTheBlankXIB" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];            
    }

    // get the elements inside the cell by tag and set a value on them
    UILabel*label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag: 1];
    label.text = @"some text";

    return cell;
}
```

Another way is to go to the NIB and set this view controller as the file owner and hook the the cell to a ivar of the view controller, like `IBOutlet UITableViewCell *tableViewCell`.

Now loading this with this instance as the owner automatically hooks the cell to the outlet tableViewCell.

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfTheBlankXIB" owner:self options:nil];
    // at this point the cell is hooked to the ivar so you get a reference to it:
    cell = self.tableViewCell;
```

Comment: But how do you separate the three cells down

Comment: Create a PNG with containing the lines and icons. Drag and drop a UIImageView and set its image to that PNG. Then drag and drop UILabels for everything else.