# Scroll view with dynamically created thumbnails on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, thumbnails

I need one long scrollable view with 2 thumbnails (wallpapers) in every row.

Every thumbnail has also a button to share and download photo, and when you click the thumbnail it shows full size wallpaper. So I was thinking about making a custom view (200x200) which will contain thumbnail and two buttons, and add them dynamically to scroll view depending how many wallpapers are on server.

Something like this:

```
NSUInteger i;
int xCoord=0;
int yCoord=0;
int thumbnailWidth=200;
int thumbnailHeight=200;
int buffer = 10;
for (i = 1; i <= [items count]; i++)
{
    UIView *aView = [[ThumbnailView alloc] initWithThumnailAtIndex: i ];
    aView.frame     = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight );
    [scrollView addSubview:aView];

    xCoord += thumbnailWidth + buffer;
    yCoord += thumbnailHeight + buffer;
}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, yCoord)];
```

Do you think that is a good way to do this?
Also, how would I handle lazy loading of thumbnails if there are a lot of thumbnails in scrollview?

Comment: Why don't you use a table view? Sound perfect for this use case. If you are deploying only for iOS6+ you can even use a collection view controller.

Comment: It must be iOS 5 compatible. How could I show 2 thumbnails in one tableview row?

Comment: Add two `UIImageView`s to the contentView of the table view cell. The photo scroll view in the photos app from Apple is a table view, I think.

Comment: But I would need two UIViews in every cell (every view has image and two buttons)

Comment: So? I have done table view cells with a lot more subviews.

Comment: Okay, I have never done it so it sounds weird to me. :D
Can you send me the code so I could check it out please?
I have never done anything similar.
Or maybe some link if you have it.

Thank you very much dasdom, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No, I won't send you code. Just make a table view cell and add as much subviews to the content view as you like. When you don't know how to do that, search for examples. I am sure you will find examples for that. I won't google for you.

Comment: Ok, I will try to find it.
I didn't mean for you to search for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everybody else here has said, use a UITableView.  I will add that you should use a custom UITableViewCell subclass.  Create the class, then use Storyboards to make a table view scene with prototype cells.  Set the class of the prototype cell to your cell subclass.  Add as many imageview, labels, buttons, whatever nonsense you want to the prototype cell on the storyboard, then hook those up to your custom class using IBOutlets.  Now when it's time to display something in the cell, just pass an object or dictionary containing all the info that's needed to the custom cell subclass, and have it populate the various view via the outlets.  Here's a tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

Comment: Is it possible to remove table lines from tableview?

Comment: Sure.  Click the table view in the storyboard editor, then select the Attributes Inspector (cmd-option-4), then set Separator Style to None.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the UITableView with custom UITableViewCell implementations. The tableview will automatically handle the recycling of the cells, so you would not need to worry as much about performance.

You could pre-load all your assets during the view initialization and then simply use them in the tableview's datasource.

Comment: But how could I show two custom cells in one row?
I need something like this: http://www.terryadamsbmx.com/blog/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Picture-4.png

Only there will be 2 images (thumbnails with controls) in every row and little space between them.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a UITableView and each cell would contain both images. Take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141179/545599)

About loading the images, try using EGOImageLoader, is very simple and effective. Here is the [Github project](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading).

Comment: Okay thank you, I will check it out.

So I should create a custom cell that has two views, every view is 100x200 and let's say 50px distance between them.
Than I can load the images in view something like this:
cell.view1.thumbnail = [UIImage imagedWithURL: @"URL"];
cell.view2.thumbnail = [UIImage imagedWithURL: @"URL"];

Is that correct?

Comment: well it will provably be cell.view1.thumbnail.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"], but you get the picture

Comment: Is it possible to remove table lines from tableview?

Comment: [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];